# Performing a logical or operation of multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logical-operators

I have a list containing some number of sublists.

```
list1=[ [True,False,True,False], [False,False,True,False],[True,False,True,True], .....]
```

I want to perform a logical or of these sublists in Python but the number of sublists is unknown. For two lists I can do `numpy.logical_or` but how can I do it for multiple sublists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ian's answer is better than my original answer. `zip` all of the lists to combine their elements columnwise, performing a transposition, and run each column into `any`:

```
>>> matrix = [
...     [True, False, True, False],
...     [False, False, True, False],
...     [True, False, True, True],
... ]
>>> [any(column) for column in zip(*matrix)]
[True, False, True, True]
```

I removed my original answer which is suboptimal.

Answer (score 3):

Following up @ggorlen's answer

```
list1 = [ 
    [True,False,True,False], 
    [False,False,True,False],
    [True,False,True,True]
]
[any(l) for l in zip(*list1)]
```

Output

```
[True, False, True, True]
```